# Separate PHP folder for admin and user

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, conditional-statements

I'm developing a application with raw PHP. But I have a problem that needs solution. I have two types of user in my application (e.g: Administrator & User).

> For administrator, I have following files under "admin" folder,
>
> > Admin (Dashboard, Change password, Add User, Profile, User List etc.)
>
> Also for user, I have following files under "account" folder
>
> > Account (My account, Change password, Edit Profile etc.)

I want, after login user can't access any files of "admin" folder. Now, after login I check the role first, if use then I redirect him/her to ***www.example.com/account/my-account.php*** but, when user hit the following url then he/she can easily access backend functionalities.

> www.example.com/admin/dashboard.php, www.example.com/admin/change-password.php, www.example.com/admin/add-user.php, www.example.com/admin/profile.php, www.example.com/admin/user-list.php

Is there any way to close the "admin" folder entrance for user?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See according to your question you have to assign a role. Though I prefer php frameworks more than a core php but still you could do.
Say you have a form where user and admin shares the same login form for logging purpose.
And you want admin to access all route and restrict few route to the user.
So , the little bit of logic, while you create admin or user you need to assign role as well.
When admin logs in ,according to it, the sql query fetches role and he is routed according to it and same goes with user also.
Set session for user and admin role. And when you enter to target after login the session you have to restrict pages not to acces by user.

Comment: Do you mean I have to do this page by page? It's not possible by folder?

Comment: since you are making some files to share between user and admin you have to make something that user can't access the admin page. I don't think folder separation will help much..